# Get a color of a button in C# wp8 VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have this working code:

```
private void Knof6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int NakljucnaBarva = RandomNumber(1, 4);
        switch (NakljucnaBarva)
        {
            case 1: Knof6.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                break;
            case 2: Knof6.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                break;
            case 3: Knof6.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                break;

        }
    }
```

and I want to get current color of a button and play a sound file if it's red.
So far I can't get any useful information from documentation or tutorials. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use the button's `Tag` member to store your custom data rather than relying re-using existing functionality.

like this:

```
Knof6.Tag = NakljucnaBarva
```

The tag member is specifically there to be

> an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information
>   about this element.

Here is the link to the doc.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. I still don't quite understand tags, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

If Knof6_Click is the click event of the button being pressed and you want to check its background colour you can do something like this.

```
private void Knof6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    Button button = (Button)sender; 
    if(button.Background == new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red))
    {
        // Play sound
    }
}
```